# how can i download s3 file using boto3(Specific period like 2:00~3:00)

Tags: python, boto3

I want create file downloader(cli utils) using boto3 python

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='***', aws_secret_access_key='***')
s3.Bucket('practice_bucket').download_file('directory/logfile_201802271000_2a31bc2d', 'logfile_2a31bc2d')
```

it works, but I want multiple files download files

like (10:00 ~ 10:20)

```
<name><year,mon,day><time><idkey>
logfile_20180227_1000_2a31bc2d
logfile_20180227_1005_31batd9b
logfile_20180227_1010_231gjqu3
logfile_20180227_1015_2jsro29f
logfile_20180227_1020_2a31bc2d
```

first, i try using `for` and `time` value

```
for i in range(-2,3):
    """
    :param time(20180227-1010)
    """
    file_name = 'logfile_{0}_2a31bc2d'.format(time)
    s3.Bucket('practice_bucket').download_file('directory/'+file_name, file_name)
```

but I can't because I don't know `idkey` of files...

So, I want download files using `time` only...

like `10:10~10:20`, `12:13~12:50` ~

but i don't know how

please some body help me thanks

Comment: You need to get a list of objects with the desired prefix then compare the time period of those objects to your range to decide whether or not to download them.

Comment: @lotyrin ummm... can you show more hint or document please?

Comment: @lotyrin fantastic I sovled my problem using your advice thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved

```
for i in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='directory/logfile_20180227'):
    bucket.download_file(i.key, i.key)
```

it will download `directory/logfile_20180227*` files